# Adding prepublish section to asp.net Core *.csproj file

Tags: asp.net, webpack, asp.net-core, publish

I use webpack in my asp.net Core MVC to bundgle js/css files and put it into the wwwroot folder after.

My folder structure looks like this on the screen:

[image]

I added "after-build" section into FrontEnd.csproj:

```
<Target Name="BuildClientAssets" BeforeTargets="Build">
  <Exec Command="npm install"/>
  <Exec Command="npm run build"/>
</Target>
```

1. **FrontEnd/node_modules** contains npm modules loaded by "npm install" command;
2. **Web/wwwroot/dist and Web/wwwroot/fonts** contains bundled js/css/fonts files, generated by "npm run build" command;

It works as expected. But it would be great if I had an oppurtunity to exec this command on publish web project.

But when I try to add prepublish section into the Web project and start publish

```
<Target Name="BuildClientAssets" BeforeTargets="Publish">
  <Exec Command="npm install"/>
  <Exec Command="npm run build"/>
</Target>
```

I get this error: **The command "npm run build" exited with code -4058**

I supposed, that it is because of the package.json located in FrontEnd project (not in the Web project), so I looked for a suitable script to start command in right way and overrrided the section:

```
<Target Name="BuildClientAssets" BeforeTargets="Publish">
  <Exec Command="npm install" />
  <Exec Command="webpack --config ../FrontEnd/webpack.config.js" />
</Target>
```

But after I get errors such as:

**Can't resolve './src/components/app/file1.ts'
ERROR in Entry module not found 0**

**Error     Can't resolve './src/components/app/file2.ts'

ERROR in Entry module not found 0**

**Error     Can't resolve 'source-map-loader'
Module not found    0**

The command is started but modules are searched still in the Web, not the FrontEnd project.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

The `npm install` isn't hitting the right folder either, you need run these commands inside the right location - probably worked in your machine because it already have the node-modules. You can keep both commands (`ǹpm install` / `npm run build`) and try to target the right location. How you can do that? You could inform the command the folder he will run.

First, set in the `PropertyGroup` section the front-end folder location

`<FrontRoot>../FrontEnd/</FrontRoot>`

and pass the property in the command lines using the `WorkingDirectory` property. It will looks like this:

```
<Target Name="BuildClientAssets" BeforeTargets="Publish">
  <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(FrontRoot)" Command="npm install"/>
  <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(FrontRoot)" Command="npm run build"/>
</Target>
```

There is a similar situation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51691626/angular-multiple-environment-with-asp-net-core-spa/53873650#53873650)