# Angular - Multiple environment with asp.net core spa

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I'm trying to build a Angular SPA application with dotnet core that tries to build angular with specific **npm command** based on the buid definition name.

The condition have the 2 last target in my csproj.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
    <TypeScriptToolsVersion>Latest</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    <SpaRoot>ClientApp\</SpaRoot>
    <DefaultItemExcludes>$(DefaultItemExcludes);$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**</DefaultItemExcludes>

    <!-- Set this to true if you enable server-side prerendering -->
    <BuildServerSideRenderer>false</BuildServerSideRenderer>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.1.1"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Gardendynamics.Commons" Version="1.0.0-ci-88" />
    <PackageReference Include="Gardendynamics.Tiers" Version="1.0.0-ci-50" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\PicaplantBack.Database\PicaplantBack.Database.csproj" IncludeAssets="All" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- Don't publish the SPA source files, but do show them in the project files list -->
    <Content Remove="$(SpaRoot)**" />
    <None Include="$(SpaRoot)**" Exclude="$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="DebugEnsureNodeEnv" BeforeTargets="Build" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' And !Exists('$(SpaRoot)node_modules') ">
    <!-- Ensure Node.js is installed -->
    <Exec Command="node --version" ContinueOnError="true">
      <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="ErrorCode" />
    </Exec>
    <Error Condition="'$(ErrorCode)' != '0'" Text="Node.js is required to build and run this project. To continue, please install Node.js from https://nodejs.org/, and then restart your command prompt or IDE." />
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Restoring dependencies using 'npm'. This may take several minutes..." />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
  </Target>

  <Target Condition=" '$(Build_DefinitionName)' == 'BackOfficePreProd' " Name="PublishRunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
    <!-- As part of publishing, ensure the JS resources are freshly built in production mode -->
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build:preprod" />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build:ssr -- --prod" Condition=" '$(BuildServerSideRenderer)' == 'true' " />

    <!-- Include the newly-built files in the publish output -->
    <ItemGroup>
      <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)dist\**; $(SpaRoot)dist-server\**" />
      <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**" Condition="'$(BuildServerSideRenderer)' == 'true'" />
      <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(DistFiles->'%(FullPath)')" Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)">
        <RelativePath>%(DistFiles.Identity)</RelativePath>
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
      </ResolvedFileToPublish>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>

  <Target Condition=" '$(Build_DefinitionName)' == 'BackOfficeProd' " Name="PublishRunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
    <!-- As part of publishing, ensure the JS resources are freshly built in production mode -->
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build -- --prod" />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build:ssr -- --prod" Condition=" '$(BuildServerSideRenderer)' == 'true' " />

    <!-- Include the newly-built files in the publish output -->
    <ItemGroup>
      <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)dist\**; $(SpaRoot)dist-server\**" />
      <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**" Condition="'$(BuildServerSideRenderer)' == 'true'" />
      <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(DistFiles->'%(FullPath)')" Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)">
        <RelativePath>%(DistFiles.Identity)</RelativePath>
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
      </ResolvedFileToPublish>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>

</Project>
```

In my VSTS build, the **build** and **publish** command are the default ones.

But in all my builds, or the production as taken, or the build failed because the condition are incorrect.

Need some help.
Thanks

Comment: Seems the issue is more related to code area, not related to VSTS side, since the build failed caused by incorrect condition, suggest you to remove the vsts tag.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had a similar problem which I needed provide few different builds. What I found is the project accepts just one step of compute files to publish. So, since your code inside the steps are similar and the difference is just one line - which indicates the build - you can use one step and bring the conditions to inside of it.

```
<Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
  <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build:prod" Condition=" '$(Build_DefinitionName)' == 'BackOfficeProd'"/>   
  <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build:preprod" Condition="'$(Build_DefinitionName)' == 'BackOfficePreProd'"/>
  <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build:ssr -- --prod" Condition="'$(BuildServerSideRenderer)' == 'true'"/>

<!-- Include the newly-built files in the publish output -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)dist\**; $(SpaRoot)dist-server\**" />
    <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**" Condition="'$(BuildServerSideRenderer)' == 'true'" />
    <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(DistFiles->'%(FullPath)')" Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)">
      <RelativePath>%(DistFiles.Identity)</RelativePath>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </ResolvedFileToPublish>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

If you have problem with the condition variable, you can use the configuration manager to set some configuration variables.

[Adding variables configuration manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkEBQ.png)

And you will be able to use these variables to build
dotnet publish -c|--Configuration Dev

Comment: thank you, this was something ive been spending all day on trying to figure out.  I knew it had to be somewhere other than the config files.

Comment: This works as expected when publishing directly from within Visual Studio, but when running dotnet publish from the cli, it seems like its not taking the configuration value.  For example, I have a build definition called 'Test' and a command that checks for that condition, but the result is that just ng build is run.  Whereas my command is <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build --prod false --configuration=dev" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Test' " />

Comment: Are you passing the test configuration variable in the dotnet publish command?